# Getting the frame id of the iframe element

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like to use the executeScript function and using frameId, however, I cannot get the frameId from the iframe element. By getting id, it will be a string, which does not match the requirement of using the executeScript.
So far I can get the  element in the content page and wish to inject the code to reach the element inside the frame. Currently, I am using allFrame:true, but I wish to improve into injecting script for the only frame.
Is there any idea?

Comment: You can use chrome.runtime.sendMessage in the content script that runs inside the iframe so that onMessage listener in the background script will have sender.frameId.

Comment: @wOxxOm Therefore, in this case, I must inject script into all frame, and distinguish which frame I wish to inject?

Comment: @wOxxOm As in some case, with more than one frame in the website, I wish the script can be simply inject into the frame I want only. Is there any solution?

Comment: It's impossible to tell so far. Try adding [MCVE](/help/mcve) to the question.